# exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0) swift 2.0

Tags: swift

I get this error in swift 2 :

> exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

My code:

```
    var learn = StructService() 
    override func  viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

     let sliderRecords = db.executeQuery ( "SELECT * FROM tablepagedesgin WHERE pdcc LIKE '%services%' ")
     for record in sliderRecords
     {
     if record.column["pdcc"]?.asString() == "services2"
     {
     let tmp = (record.column["pdtitle"]!.asString())! 
     learn.pdtitle.append(tmp) //exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0) 

     }
    }}
```

In my Class :

```
class StructService
{

 var pdtitle:[String]!
 var mainTitle:String!
 var expanded: Bool!
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`pdtitle` is declared but not initialized. So it's `nil` and the code crashes.

It's always a very bad habit to declare class properties as implicit unwrapped optionals as an alibi not to write or use an initializer.

If a property is supposed to be optional, declare it as regular optional.

In this example the array is initialized empty, the string is an optional and the Bool is declared with a default value.

```
class StructService
{
   var pdtitle = [String]()
   var mainTitle : String?
   var expanded = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `pdtitle` in `StructService` is not initialized, so it doesn't exist.

Change your code to

```
class StructService {
     var pdtitle:[String] = []
     var mainTitle:String!
     var expanded: Bool!
 }
```